# Steady-state Kalman filter question

Tags: kalman-filters

I'm reverse-engineering DSP code and there's a steady-state Kalman filter in it. Because it is a steady-state Kalman filter, the matrix $K$ is fixed. However,  I'm a puzzled about the state update equations .

The reverse-engineered state update equation is the following :

$$s[n] = (A-KH^T)s[n-1] + K u[n]$$ where $u[n]$ is a scalar input.

The Kalman error is evaluated using the previous state and they compare it the current input to the filter.

$$e[n] = u[n] - H^Ts[n-1]$$

The filter is tracking a sine wave and the error indeed goes down to 0 after some time.

Why does it work? Why are the filter equations different than the formulae in Steven M. Kay's book. It seems *wrong* to compare the current input with the previous state and not the current state.

Here are the 2 relevant equations in Kay book.

**Prediction**

$$ s[n|n-1] = As[n-1|n-1] $$

**Correction**

$$ s[n|n] = s[n|n-1] + K[n](u[n]-H^Ts[n|n-1]) $$

In this application, this is steady-state Kalman Filter, so K[n] is actually a constant.

Comment: Can you provide the details of KF equations in Kay's book? Thanks

Comment: @Maxtron I added the 2 relevant equations. I did not include the Kalman gain equations since the gain is constant.

Comment: Hi: I'm not certain because I don't see the original equations for the KF in your question but check out the link below. The difference you point out regarding the equations may be due to the fact that there are two different ( and equivalent ) formulations of the KF in the literature.   https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58221/kalman-filter-order-of-update-step/58231#58231

Comment: the original equation (from the reverse-engineered code) is the first equation. The last 2 are from Kay book.

Comment: @markleeds Thanks, I will check the thread.

Comment: @Ben, Can you share the matrices and some measurements? How sure are you about inferring the form correctly from the code?

Comment: @Royi I will soon. I need to change the matrices a bit because of the NDA.